Create new objects in Powershell pipeline
I want to copy recursively certain files to a target directory but keeping the same folder structure.
I'd like to be able to do something like the following:
gci -Recurse -File *.csproj | rvpa -Relative | select { @{ src=$_ ; dst=[System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($baseDir + $_) } } | % { mkdir $_.dst && cp $_.src $_.dst }

Unfortunately, the above doesn't work — the select (and other variants I've tried) is not creating the objects as I'm expecting, for example, if I just output the select I see something like:



@{ src=$_ ; dst=[System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($baseDir + $_) }




{[src, .\path\to\csproj1\csproj1.csproj], [dst, c:\base\dir.\path\to\csproj1]}


{[src, .\path\to\csproj2\csproj2.csproj], [dst, c:\base\dir.\path\to\csproj2]}


{[src, .\path\to\csproj3\csproj3.csproj], [dst, c:\base\dir.\path\to\csproj3]}



It seems like these are just plain strings. Can you advise me on how can I do this?




Alias
cmdlet




gci
Get-ChildItem


rvpa
Resolve-Path


select
Select-Object


%
ForEach-Object


cp
Copy-Item




I could prob avoid the select and repeat src/dst expressions in the foreach but I'm curious now if this is possible to do

'&&' don't work in PowerShell, use ';' instead

@Someone it does work in powershell 7+

The syntax for calculated properties in your code should be:
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File *.csproj | Resolve-Path -Relative | Select-Object @(
    @{ Name = 'src'; Expression = { $_ }}
    @{ Name = 'dst'; Expression = { [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($baseDir + $_) }})

The about Calculated Properties and Select-Object documentations explain this syntax in detail.
As for the expression:
[System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($baseDir + $_)

It will not evaluate correctly because Resolve-Path -Relative prepends .\ to each path, it would make more sense to just do all this evaluation inside the ForEach-Object scriptblock and remove Select-Object from the equation.
An alternative that would work well with GetDirectoryName is to use Path.GetRelativePath as this method doesn't prepend .\ to the outputted path:
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File *.csproj |
    ForEach-Object { [System.IO.Path]::GetRelativePath($pwd.Path, $_) } |
    Select-Object @(
        @{ Name = 'src'; Expression = { $_ }}
        @{ Name = 'dst'; Expression = { [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($baseDir + $_) }})

However this method is .NET Core 2.0+, it doesn't exist in .NET Framework (Windows PowerShell 5.1), the simplest way there is just a .SubString:
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File *.csproj |
    ForEach-Object { $_.FullName.Substring($pwd.Path.Length + 1) } |
    Select-Object @(
        @{ Name = 'src'; Expression = { $_ }}
        @{ Name = 'dst'; Expression = { [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($baseDir + $_) }})


Thanks! I tried using Select-Object with @(...) form but I got an error when passing $_.dst to the mkdir, it said: "Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.". I did it with Select-Object @{Name='...'; Expression={...}}, @{Name='...'; Expression={...}}. The final command was: gci -Recurse -File *.csproj | % { [System.IO.Path]::GetRelativePath($PWD.Path, $_.FullName) } | select @{Name='src';Expression={$_}}, @{Name='dst';Expression={[System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($baseDir+$_)}} | % {mkdir $_.dst && cp $_.src $_.dst}
